# Unity 3D: How I can make a Player with a Character Controller can push another Player with Character Controller?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm new into unity and I'm following tutorials. I'm making a script that moves a 3D player with a CharacterController and I attached another script that adds the ability to push RigidBodys, but how I can make the Player push another Player? It just collides but nothing happens and I don't want to make it a rigidbody.

```
//Script that i use as PlayerController
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float horizontalMove;
    public float verticalMove;
    private Vector3 playerInput;

    public CharacterController player;

    public float playerSpeed;
    public Vector3 movePlayer;
    public float gravity = 9.8f;
    public float fallVelocity;
    public float jumpForce;

    public Camera mainCamera;
    private Vector3 camForward;
    private Vector3 camRight;

    public bool isOnSlope = false;
    private Vector3 hitNormal;
    public float slideVelocity;
    public float slopeForceDown;
    private PushRigidBody pushRigid;
    public float pushPlus;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        //Obtengo el componente Script "PushRigidBody" para poder usar sus metodos y cambiar variables con sus mutadores
        pushRigid = GetComponent<PushRigidBody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        verticalMove = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        playerInput = new Vector3(horizontalMove, 0, verticalMove);
        playerInput = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(playerInput, 1);

        camDirection();

        movePlayer = playerInput.x * camRight + playerInput.z * camForward;

        movePlayer = movePlayer * playerSpeed;

        player.transform.LookAt(player.transform.position + movePlayer);

        SetGravity();


        PlayerSkills();
        player.Move(movePlayer * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);


    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

    }

    void camDirection()
    {
        camForward = mainCamera.transform.forward;
        camRight = mainCamera.transform.right;

        camForward.y = 0;
        camRight.y = 0;

        camForward = camForward.normalized;
        camRight = camRight.normalized;
    }

    //Funcion para habilidades de jugador
    public void PlayerSkills()
    {
        if (player.isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {

            fallVelocity = jumpForce;
            movePlayer.y = fallVelocity;

        }
        //Detecta si presiono la tecla para golpear objeto y aventarlo, si la aprieta aumenta la fuerza con la que golpea, si no, la vuelve a dejar como estaba
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            pushRigid.SetPushPower(pushPlus);
        }
        else
        {
            pushRigid.SetPushPower( 0f );
        }

    }

    void SetMov(Vector3 vector)
    {
        movePlayer = movePlayer - vector;
    }

    void SetGravity()
    {

        if (player.isGrounded)
        {
            fallVelocity = -gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            movePlayer.y = fallVelocity;
        }
        else
        {
            fallVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            movePlayer.y = fallVelocity;
        }

        SlideDown();
    }
    //Compara si esta o no en una rampa y aplica fuerzas para deslizar
    public void SlideDown()
    {
        //isOnSlope = angulo >= angulo maximo del charcontroller
        isOnSlope = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, hitNormal) >= player.slopeLimit;

        if (isOnSlope)
        {
            movePlayer.x += ((1f - hitNormal.y) * hitNormal.x) * slideVelocity;
            movePlayer.z += ((1f - hitNormal.y) * hitNormal.z) * slideVelocity;

            movePlayer.y += slopeForceDown;

        }

    }

    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        hitNormal = hit.normal;
    }
}
```

```
----------


///Script that i use for push rigidbodys
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PushRigidBody : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float pushPower = 2.0f;
    private float pushPowerPlus = 0f;


    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        Rigidbody body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;


        if (body == null || body.isKinematic)
        {

            return;
        }

        //Si caemos encima de un objeto no queremos empujarlo, se pone encima de el
        if (hit.moveDirection.y < -0.8)
        {
            return;
        }

        Vector3 pushDir = new Vector3(hit.moveDirection.x, 0, hit.moveDirection.z);
        ;

        body.velocity = pushDir * (pushPower + pushPowerPlus);

    }

    public void SetPushPower(float pushPowerVar)
    {
        pushPowerPlus = pushPowerVar;
    }


}
```

Comment: apply force on collision

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a `RigidBody` to move the character, it is easier if you also don't use a `RigidBody` for pushing, and implement it as you did using the `body.move` on the update (which forces the body to move every game tick)

So you could add a new Vector to the players, the push force, and when you collide you set the push force vector of the other player you collided with.

Then on the update, you add the push vector to the movement when calling `move` and make it lower until it reaches 0 to create the feel of deaceleration.

You can use the built in linear interpolation in Unity (Lerp) to make this "vector smoothly go down to zero".

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this
 1. Add Collider and rigidBody (both required) to object to be pushed and object that'll push and use RigidBody's `MovePosition` [RigidBody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) functionality for moving object that'll push then it'll push other rigid bodies unity's physics engine when it moves toward them.
 2. If you want to push objects on a certain event happening you can do all the above but on the event happening you can use Rigidbody's `AddForce` [RigidBody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) functionality.

Good Luck!

Edit: I believe CharachterController acts as a collider in GameObjects so you may not need to add colliders.